# How do I find Frost the Horse if he runs away during "Promises to Keep"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I find Frost the Horse if he runs away during the quest "Promises to Keep"? I got attacked while riding Frost, dismounted to fight, and then the horse ran away. Now I can't complete the quest.

Is there any way to restart the quest or find Frost again?

Comment: I haven't played the game but I must say I love the name of the quest, having a horse named Frost and all

Comment: Have you looked back at the Black-Briar lodge?

Comment: Frost's ID is 000cb276, I'm with his body and have him targeted, but the resurrect cheat doesn't seem to be doing anything. Oh well :(

Comment: For those who (like myself) didn't get the reference: http://www.ketzle.com/frost/snowyeve.htm

Answer (score 6):

From the comments above:

> Frost's ID is 000cb276, I'm with his body and have him targeted, but the resurrect cheat doesn't seem to be doing anything. Oh well :( – Abby Nov 29 at 1:41

Actually it's ID is 00097E1F  (source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Frost_%28Horse%29)

If Frost ran away, player.moveto 00097E1F should  move you to him.

Comment: `player.placeatme 00097e1e` moves him to you. `player.moveto 00097e1f` moves you to him.

Comment: -1, doesn't say how to find him on consoles (without cheating).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the ID to resurrect a dead NPC if you have his body: open the console, target the body (click on the body once) and type `resurrect`.

Mine is MIA God knows where so I don't have his body to do this trick; I guess I'll have to find the bloody ID to teleport to him or something.

Comment: yea idk where the hell mine ran off too i tried looking for him but im not about to walk around for hrs til i find him

Answer (score 0):

He probably got into a fight and died. Frost seems to be a bit more aggressive in combat than other horses and will fight with pretty much anything, including dragons. For me, he died to a couple of wolves that I didn't notice him run to attack while I took off in another direction. I found his body, next to one of the wolf corpses, all I need to know now is how to resurrect him. You can apparently resurrect any NPC, just have to know their ID to type into console. Not sure how to get this though and I can't find it online anywhere.

Comment: I don't know If He died wouldn't the quest fail than if the horse died.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move Frost to you instead of moving you to him, you can use the following commands in the console:

> Prid 00097E1F
> moveto player

`Prid` selects an object by form ID and `moveto player` moves the selected object to the player.

A comment on another answer mentioned the possibility of using `player.placeatme 00097E1F`. That may work for this particular quest (I haven't tried,) but, just as a head's up, that will create a *new* instance of the NPC instead of moving the existing one to you. The Prid/moveto command combination listed above will move the existing one to you. I'm not sure whether it makes a difference in this case, but it can in other cases (for example, if Serana goes running off in the Soul Cairn.)

Answer (score -1):

In the console, click on him with your cursor and type `resurrect`.  Voilà!

Comment: *"click on him with your cursor"* - uhh...

Answer (score -1):

To resurrect a horse for sure, (I noticed the normal resurrect command didn't work on Frost for me) try targeting the body and typing `resurrect 1`.  Should work without fail.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Arquade! Please refrain from repeating something already posted without reason.

Answer (score -3):

When you do the quest with Frost, you can chouse to keep the horse.
I have Frost evrey where i go but at some time i lost him becouse i rided another horse.
When i had him, he died 2 times, but i managed to resurrect him :
in console: prid 97E1F [enter]
            resurrect
but now i cant track him.. anyway, it's a very good horse, and he is good in combat, he doesen't run.